# Showing a functor has no right adjoint

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let ${\cal C}$ be the category of groups.

Let ${\cal C}'$ be the full subcategory of ${\cal C}$ with objects the class of abelian groups.

Let $F$ be the inclusion of ${\cal C}'$ into ${\cal C}$.

I think $F$ has a left-adjoint which is the functor that takes a group to its abelianization, and the $F$ has no right adjoint but am not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that abelianization is left adjoint to the forgetful/inclusion functor. If $F$ had a right adjoint, then $F$ would itself be a left adjoint, which would imply that it preserved colimits. The easiest way to show that $F$ has no right adjoint is to give an example of a colimit that is not preserved by $F$.

Consider coproducts. Do you know what the coproduct is in the category of groups (if you don't know, it might be a fun exercise to work out)? In the category of abelian groups? Do they agree?